# What is the best way to debug Bootstrap.groovy?

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I am inserting some data into the database but some objects aren't inserting even though I can't see any validation errors.  What is the best way to error with stacktrace or with sql so i can figure out what is wrong?

for example I do , new XXXXX(property: "blah").save(flush:true)

I don't see errors on startup (grails run-app) but i also don't see my data.  I do see the data for many of my objects so i'm sure it's something about my objects, validation or even associations but I need a simple way to see the issue in the log/console...

i'm sure this is easy, but tia...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend letting save() throw an exception if it fails during bootstrap, since a validation error will be caused by your code, not user input.

```
new Xxxxx(property: "blah").save(failOnError: true)
```

The exception will contain a pretty wordy block of text, but check the first line, which will look like:

> grails.validation.ValidationException:
>   Validation Error(s) occurred during
>   save():
>
> Field error in object
>   'mypackage.Xxxxx' on field
>   'myProperty': rejected value [null]

Comment: A robust set of unit tests would negate the need for this, for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

First and formost, I'd write a unit test around your domain.  If that seems to work, but you're still having issues in Bootstrap, for each save, I then check the domain for errors..

```
def xxxxx = new XXXXX(...)
xxxxx.save(flush:true)
def errors = xxxxx.errors
```

I'll then put a break point in there so I can inspect the errors object.  Otherwise, you can println the errors object, and usually glean enough from that to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Should be `def xxxxx new XXXXX(...); xxxxx.save(flush:true); def errors = xxxxx.errors` since save() returns null if it doesn't validate

Comment: Yep, got in a hurry. Fixed.  Thanks.