# creating a tree-like structure in GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, tree, grails-orm

I am trying to correctly define a **tree structure** in GORM and having trouble.

i have one domain object:

```
class Navigation {
    Navigation parent
    List children;
    String name;

    static belongsTo = [parent: Navigation]
    static hasMany = [children: Navigation]

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable: true);
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
void testTree() {
    Navigation root = new Navigation(name:"root");
    Navigation top1 = new Navigation(name:"home");
    Navigation top2 = new Navigation(name:"services");

    root.addToChildren(top1).addToChildren(top2).save(flush: true);

    Navigation s1 = new Navigation(name:"plumbing")
    Navigation s2 = new Navigation(name:"baking")

    top2.addToChildren(s1).addToChildren(s2).save(flush: true);

    Navigation t = Navigation.findByName("root")
    assert t.children.size() == 2
}
```

if i run this test, i get this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.Navigation.addToChildren() is applicable for argument types: (grails.Navigation) values: [grails.Navigation : null]
```

and if i place the contents of that test into boostrap, i **dont** get that error, and the application starts up, except the **navigation table is empty**

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: I believe you'll wish to utilize `mappedBy`: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock the Navigation domain so that you can use the GORM methods in your unit test.

Add this to the top of your test case:

```
mockDomain(Navigation)
```

Comment: I don't know why your navigation table is empty if you put the code in Bootstrap, but I think it must be a bug in your Bootstrap code. I checked that this test isn't just "testing the domain mocking code" by making it an integration test, and removing the call to mockDomain(). It still passes. Most likely, your navigation table is empty after Bootstrap because the domain didn't save successfully. Add [failOnError: true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355329/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-bootstrap-groovy/5357760#5357760) to your Bootstrap saves as a sanity check.

Comment: you are correct sir, there was an issue in my bootstrap code, something important didnt get saved and caused everything to fail